# Run-on string when formatter believes a string ending back tick is escaped

Tags: bug, code-formatting

I came across [this answer's code snippet](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59207255/160527). In Golang, strings enclosed in backticks are taken as a raw string. It doesn't parse for escape sequences. The code formatter erroneously colors the rest of the code as if it were in a multi-line string literal.

This is true even if you explicitly specify the language as Golang as I have here:

```golang
x := `\r\n\`
fmt.Println(len(x)) // 5
```

EDIT: [Submitted a bug with Google's code-prettify](https://github.com/google/code-prettify/issues/614)

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, the parsing is done by [Google's code-prettify](https://github.com/google/code-prettify) plugin; not much SO can do about it...

Comment: Yup, Heretic Monkey is correct. File a bug with Google Prettify. Once they get it fixed and merged into master (note: from experience, this takes approximately infinite time), then Stack Overflow can pull the latest version and it'll be fixed here, too.